# Finding the Equation of a Straight Line on a Log-Log Plot Given Two Points

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions, interpolation, monomial-function

Given two discrete points on a log-log plot and a defined minimum value on both axes, how would you determine the equation of the line that runs through both points?

I'm aware of how straight lines on a log-log plot are described by monomials, but I'm not sure exactly how to work backwards to that monomial given two points on the line.

Comment: Can you upload the plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a power function

$$ y=bx^m $$

graphed on a log-log scale, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\log y&=&m\log x+\log b\\\
Y&=&mX+B
\end{eqnarray}

where $Y=\log y$, $X=\log x$, and $B=\log b$.

So given two points $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ on a log-log graph we have

$$ m=\frac{Y_1-Y_0}{X_1-X_0}=\frac{\log(y_1/y_0)}{\log(x_1/x_0)}\tag{1} $$

And we have

\begin{eqnarray}
B&=&Y-mX \tag{2}\\\
\log b&=&\log y-m\log x\\\
b&=&10^{\log y-\log x^m}\\\
b&=&\frac{y}{x^m}
\end{eqnarray}

**ADDENDUM:** Re-reading your question, I think you only need $B$ from equation (2) after finding the value $m$ in equation (1), rather than the value of $b$. You can use $Y=\log y_0$, $X=\log x_0$.

Comment: Ah, I was definitely overthinking this. As soon as I saw the substitution of the log values into the general line equation, the rest became clear. Very helpful, thanks!

Comment: This also helped me realize B is the intersection of the line with x=1, not whatever arbitrary axis I have set up.