# Finding the Equation of a Straight Line on a Semi-Log Plot Given Two Points

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions

I want to learn how to create a straight line on an Excel semi-log graph of my data. An internet search pointed me to a similar answer on math.stackexchange.com:  [Finding the Equation of a Straight Line on a Log-Log Plot Given Two Points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3245738/finding-the-equation-of-a-straight-line-on-a-log-log-plot-given-two-points).  But this is for a log-log chart, and I’ve not been able to figure out how to do this for a semi-log plot, where the x-axis is a linear time scale, and only the y-axis is logarithmic. I don’t see any answer to my question in the list of similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

When you plot a function $y = f(x)$ on an ordinary graph (no logarithmic scale),
the horizontal distance of any point is proportional to $x$,
the vertical distance is proportional to $y$,
and a straight line has an equation like

$$  y = m x + b.  $$

This is true even if the horizontal and vertical scales are not equal, for example if the $x$ axis has marks labeled $1,$ $2,$ $3$ and the $y$-axis is labeled in millions.

When you plot functions on a log-log graph,
the horizontal distance of any point is proportional to $\ln(x)$,
the vertical distance is proportional to $\ln(y)$,
and a straight line has an equation like

$$  \ln(y) = m \ln(x) + B.  $$

If you want $y$ as a function of $x$ you need to solve that equation for $y,$
and you get $y = b x^m$ where $b = e^B,$ as shown in
[Finding the Equation of a Straight Line on a Log-Log Plot Given Two Points](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3245738/139123).

Note that this works even when (as is often the case) the logarithmic scales are marked in powers of some number other than $e,$ because the logarithm of any base is proportional to the logarithm of any other base.

When you plot functions on a semi-log graph with $y$ plotted on a logarithmic scale and $x$ plotted on a linear scale,
the horizontal distance of any point is proportional to $x$,
the vertical distance is proportional to $\ln(y)$,
and a straight line has an equation like

$$  \ln(y) = m x + B.  $$

Solving for $y,$

\begin{align}
y &= e^{m x + B} \\
&= e^B \cdot (e^m)^x \\
&= b k^x
\end{align}

where $b = e^B$ and $k = e^m.$
So you're looking for an equation in the form $y = b k^x$ with suitable constants $b$ and $k.$

---

Just for the sake of completeness, if you happen to be plotting data on a semi-log graph with a logarithmic scale for $x$ and a linear scale for $y,$
the horizontal distance of any point is proportional to $\ln(x)$,
the vertical distance is proportional to $y$,
and a straight line has an equation like

$$  y = m \ln(x) + b.  $$